# Numbers key combination for "fill down" and "fill right"

Tags: macbook-pro, numbers

I want to be able to fill down certain formulas in a spreadsheet.

I DO NOT want to use the mouse or trackpad. I only want to know if there is a key combination like Excel's command+D or command+R

I do not even see in any of the menus a fill down or fill right.

Thanks in advance

Doc